# Play Scala Slick query incredibly slow on AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, amazon-rds, slick

I'm currently encountring a performance issue with play slick hitting a Postgresql database on AWS RDS. The app was running quite well 2 days ago but now some queries are freezing the app.

A join query with a result of only 8 rows would take up to 2300ms and one resulting with 30 row is taking more than 4000ms.

Here is the query performed as an example:

```
protected def jobOfferQuery = for {
  (((mission, client), process), clientCompany) <- jobOffers
    .joinLeft(users).on(_.clientId === _.userId)
    .joinLeft(processes).on(_._1.offerId === _.jobOfferId)
    .joinLeft(companies)
} yield (mission, client, process, clientCompany)
```

Here is my slick configuration for my play app:

```
database {
 dataSourceClass = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
 properties = {
   serverName = ${app.postgres.host}
   portNumber = ${app.postgres.port}
   databaseName = ${app.postgres.db}
   user = ${app.postgres.user}
   password = ${app.postgres.password}
 }
 poolName = ${app.postgres.poolName}
 numThreads=5

 driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
```

}

How can it be so slow ? Should I add more hikarycp configuration ?

Thank you so much for helping me out, much appreciated ..

Comment: Have you tried to check wich query slick is generates and than this query with explain command https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-explain.html?

Comment: Found the solution .. The third join was without a condition is simply killing the performance. It was an idiot mistake on my side.